# vscode prevent automatic imports from specific node module

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an angular/ionic project that has `selenium-webdriver` somewhere in the dependency tree and sometimes the auto-import imports wrong things from it (like: `Alert` or `Storage`)

Is it possible to prevent VS Code to import automatically things from some installed packaged? Like a auto import forbidden list?